# through:オプション以外でアクセスするために外部キーを追加してもよいか

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

ホテルの予約システムを実装しています。

```
  # 予約テーブル
  class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :plan, inverse_of: :reservations
    delegate :room, to: :plan, allow_nil: true
  end

  # 予約プランテーブル
  class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :reservations, inverse_of: :plan
    belongs_to :room, inverse_of: :plans
  end

  # 部屋テーブル
  class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :plans, inverse_of: :room
    has_many :reservations, through: :plans
  end
```

このような関連の時、[ある部屋の予約状況を知りたい]時
`ReservationsController`では

```
  @reservation = Room.find(params[:id]).reservations
```

のようにしておくと 中間テーブルの役割を果たす`plans`が中でJoinされて
[予約プランが一つでもないと予約状況が参照できない]状態となります。

そのため `reservations`に`room_id`を追加して直接参照したいのですが
`plans`にも`room_id`があるためDB設計的に冗長なのではと感じてます。

この場合、どのように設計をすれば良いでしょうか。

Comment: Location.findはおそらくRoom.findが正、という理解ですが合っていますか？

Comment: その通りです。修正しました!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

要件に依ると思います。

今のモデルの設計だと、「プランなしでは予約できない」というルールに見えます。
もし本当にそうだとしたら、「プランがないなら予約は参照できない」という状況でも困らないはずです。

ですが、「プランがなくても予約を参照したい」ということなので、実際は「プランなしでも予約は可能」なんだと思います。（ふつうのホテルの業務を想像してもたぶんそんな気がします）

さらにいうと、「部屋がプランを持つ」点に少し違和感があります。
これはプランによって使える部屋が限定されるということなんでしょうか？

個人的な感覚でいうと、こんなモデル設計になる気がします。

- Room has many reservations
- Plan has many reservations
- Reservation has room (必須：予約は必ず部屋を持つ)
- Reservation has plan (任意：プランなしで予約されることもある)
- 部屋とプランは直接関連しない

いずれにしても、部屋と予約とプランの関係性（業務ルール）を考えて、今のモデル構造が妥当かどうかを検証することが先かなと思います。
妥当であれば、Reservationにroom_idを追加するのもアリだと思います。

Comment: 任意: プランなしでも予約されることがある。点納得です! 設計上は[プランは必須]にしているのに[プラン無しで参照したい]というのは矛盾でした。
しっかり吟味して設計します!!

Answer (score 1):

`Reservation`に`room_id`を追加した場合、`Reservation`と`Room`の間に`Reservation`-`Plan`-`Room`という関連と、`Reservation`-`Room`という2経路の関連が出来ることになるので、この整合性を担保する必要があります。

整合性の担保は

- モデルを使う側に押しつける
- モデルの側でコールバックなどを使って実現する
- DB側でトリガなどで実現する

等考えられますが、いずれにせよ結構面倒です

複数経路での関連が生じるのは直ちにNGではないのですが、本当に必要性があるのか、設計で回避できないのかは検討する必要があるでしょう。

---

ところで、このモデル設計では、一般的には可能でなければならないはずの「一つの予約で複数の部屋を申し込む」ということが管理できません。また「予約プラン」というのが単なる中間テーブルなのか、いわゆる「スタンダードプラン」とか「レディースプラン」とかの「プラン」なのかどちらとも読み取れるのですが、どちらであるにしても違和感があります。そもそもの設計に問題があるような気がします。

Comment: [整合性の担保]、、なるほど。 挙げていただいた内容で処理するより設計で避けられそうです。
また、「一つの予約で複数の部屋を申し込む」ことはなく、
予約プランは「スタンダードプラン」等を格納するマスターの役目を果たす予定です。

なので`plans`と`rooms`はマスターの役割を果たし、`reservation`で各情報を管理するよう再設計いたします:)